# Avro Schema from JSON document in golang

Tags: python, go, schema, avro, apache-pulsar

I tried to create JSON parser which will create a AVRO schema. I was unsuccessful in implementing it

I am looking for golang Code which **infers AVRO Schema from JSON **document. if I can get a python code that would also be good

I tried to write a json parser to create golang code to generate AVRO Schema from a JSON document

Pls note this code produces a generic object notation which I intend to make it avro schema. I have put the expected schema in the end of code

```
import json
import urllib


TYPES = {
    type(1): 'long',
    type(1.2): 'double',
    type("abc"): 'string',
    type(u"abc"): 'string',
    type(True): 'boolean',
    type([]): 'array',
    type(()): 'array',
    type({}): 'object',
    type(None): 'null',
}

COMPOUND_TYPES = frozenset(['array', 'object'])
SCALARS_TYPES = set(TYPES.values()) - COMPOUND_TYPES


def parse_sample(item, paths=None, base=None, avro=None):
    avro = avro or {}
    base = base or ()
    paths = paths or {}  # path container and counters
    paths.setdefault(base, 0)
    paths[base] += 1
    type_ = TYPES.get(type(item), "any")
    base1 = base + (type_,)
    paths.setdefault(base1, 0)
    print("ppp---  ", paths)
    print("bbb+++", base1)
    print("  tttt ",type_)

    if type_ in SCALARS_TYPES:
        paths[base1] += 1
        # avro.append({"name": k, "type": TYPES.get(type(item), "any")})
    elif type_ == "array":
        paths[base1] += 1
        base1b = base1 + (None,)  # adding extra place for possible extensions (eg array index)
        paths.setdefault(base1b, 0)
        for subitem in item:
            parse_sample(subitem, paths=paths, base=base1b)
    elif type_ == "object":
        avro.update({ " type": "record", "name": "Record"})
        paths[base1] += 1
        for (k, subitem) in item.items():
            base1b = base1 + (k,)
            print( subitem, TYPES.get(type(subitem), "any"), paths, base1b)
            parse_sample(subitem, paths=paths, base=base1b)

    # print(paths)
    # print(avro)
    return paths

def from_json(url):
    u = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    return json.loads(u)


def guess_schema(s):
    paths = parse_sample(s)
    # print(paths)
    # return build_schema(paths)




json_content = {
    "timestamp": 1661193367,
    "plant": "M14",
    "group": "g3",
    "device": "Sensor3",
    "parameter": "Power",
    "value": 100.3000000000001,
    "unit": "V",
    "limits": {
        "class": "A",
        "high": 200.2,
        "low": 32
    },
    "portfolio": {
        "id": "M00"
    }
}

def write(schema, filename):
    schema_str = json.dumps(schema)
    # print(schema)
    # print(json.dumps(schema))
    with open(filename, 'w') as x:
        json.dump(schema, x, indent=4 )

# write(avro_guess(json_content), "guess_avro.json")
paths = parse_sample(json_content)
# print(paths)

"""
Expected schema

{
    "type": "object",
    "name": "Record",
    "fields": {
        "device": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
        },
        "parameter": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
        },
        "plant": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
        },
        "timestamp": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "long"
        },
        "unit": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
        },
        "value": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "double"
        },
        "group": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
        },
        "limits": {
            "type": "object",
            "name": "Record",
            "fields": {
                "class": {
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "high": {
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "double"
                },
                "low": {
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "double"
                }
            }
        },
        "portfolio": {
            "type": "object",
            "name": "Record",
            "fields": {
                "id": {
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
"""
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What have you tried. Share your code

Comment: Shared the code @AB since I am new to golang I thought I will first write the code in python and then convert it into golang